How to export xlsx from a WebGL webpage made with Unity?
I would like to ask everyone
I created a WebGL file in Unity and wanted to export it to xlsx file (Excel)
Using the EPPlus suite
The function of my source code is as follows
public void HourConvertJsonToXlsxBar()
{
    string jsonData = JsonUtility.ToJson(HourVoltageManager.voltageData, true);
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VoltageData>(jsonData);

    ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial; // 添加這行
    using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

        worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Date";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "MeterID";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 3].Value = "Hour";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 4].Value = "Voltage";

        int row = 2;

        foreach (var record in data.Records)
        {
            string date = record.Date;

            foreach (var meterVoltage in record.MeterVoltages)
            {
                string meterId = meterVoltage.MeterID;

                if (meterVoltage.HourlyVoltages != null)
                {
                    int meterStartRow = row;

                    foreach (var hourlyVoltage in meterVoltage.HourlyVoltages)
                    {
                        worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value = date;
                        worksheet.Cells[row, 2].Value = meterId;
                        worksheet.Cells[row, 3].Value = $"{hourlyVoltage.Hour}:00";
                        worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Value = hourlyVoltage.Voltage;

                        row++;
                    }

                    var chart = worksheet.Drawings.AddChart($"VoltageVerticalBarChart_{meterId}", eChartType.ColumnClustered);
                    chart.Title.Text = $"Voltage Over Time - Meter ID: {meterId}";
                    chart.SetPosition(row - meterVoltage.HourlyVoltages.Count, 0, 5, 0);
                    chart.SetSize(600, 400);

                    var series = chart.Series.Add(worksheet.Cells[meterStartRow, 4, row - 1, 4], worksheet.Cells[meterStartRow, 3, row - 1, 3]);
                    series.Header = "Voltage";
                    chart.XAxis.Title.Text = "Hour";
                    chart.YAxis.Title.Text = "Voltage";

                    row += 10;
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log($"Meter ID: {meterId} 的 HourlyReadings 為 null");
                }
            }
        }

        byte[] fileData = package.GetAsByteArray();
        string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(fileData);
        string fileName = "HourWithVerticalBarChart.xlsx";

        // 使用 JavaScript 函式觸發下載
        string jsFunction = $@"
            function triggerFileDownload(fileName, base64Data) {{
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = 'data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,' + base64Data;
                link.download = fileName;
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                document.body.removeChild(link);
            }}
            triggerFileDownload('{fileName}', '{base64String}');
        ";

        Application.ExternalEval(jsFunction);
    }

    Debug.Log("JSON data has been converted to Excel with vertical bar charts for each MeterID.");
}

However, when throwing the packaged WebGL file to Apache Server for execution, the following error message will appear:

Can you please tell me how to solve this problem?
Thank you so much!
I went to Debug in the direction that the EEPlus package does not support WebGL, and tried changing the package and changing the Code. ways to try, tried ClosedXML, GemBox.Spreadsheet, OpenXMLSDK suite and embedded The SheetJS suite uses JavaScript to convert data into xlsx files... and found that different BUGs were generated, but There is also no way to export the xlsx file...
